# Regular expression for tweets that contain only hashtags

Tags: regex, r, twitter

I'm using R and have a large dataframe of tweets. I would like a grep call that would select tweets that are made up of nothing but hashtags (want to exclude these from final dataframe).

My initial grep effort:

```
hashtagonly_tweets_INDEX = grep("^#\\w*[^\\w]", allTweets$V1,
                            value=F,
                            ignore.case = T,
                            fixed=F)
```

I was hoping this would select multiple words beginning with hashtag ^#\w* and not select words without a hashtag [^\w].

However, I've clearly run out of talent at this point as the types of tweets this collects still contain text among the hashtags, eg:

> #wtf is even happening right now. this truck is driving 50 down the center of the highway. #learntodrive
>
> #WhatGrindsMyGears When someone pulls out in front of me then never proceeds to go the speed limit or above. #roadrage
>
> #Traffic in #Westminster #travel #roadrage #transport #London #tourism #sightseeing #dark #clouds

Any advice much appreciated,

thanks

Comment: Do you want to only extract `#wtf` from the first line, `#WhatGrindsMyGears, #roadrage` from 2nd line...?

Comment: When asking for regular expression help, provide clear input and desired output. Make sure to include positive and negative results. You need to be as explicit as possible. All of your examples seem to have at least one word that's not a hashtag.

Comment: You might want to look into `qdapRegex::rm_hash`

Comment: Sorry  - my first post wasn't clear. My goal is to select tweets that only consist of hashtags. For example, say I have three tweets:

`* TWEET 1: #ThingsIHateAboutIowa Drivers. They nvr seem to be on any sort of schdule, and most of thm dnt know hw to merge to save their life #roadrage`

`* TWEET 2: #ThingsThatAnnoyMe when people go 35 mph in a 55 zone, people who dont use their turn signals &amp; sucky drivers in general #roadrage`

`* TWEET 3: #vroomvroom #roadrage`

I would want a regex that would select only TWEET 3 as it consists of only hashtags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I well understand your question, here is a regex that matches tweets that only consist of hashtags:

```
^\s*(?:#\w+\s*)+$
```

Comment: I'm getting FALSE when I run `grepl("/^\\s*(?:#\\w+\\s*)+$/", "#hello #world")` - why doesn't this work?  @JESUISCHARLIE can you show an example in R along with your regexp?

Comment: @ScottWilson: Sorry, I don't know `R` regex syntax. I've just given a generic regex

Comment: @SteveTrawley Would you please show how you used in this in an R program?

Comment: @ScottWilson - this works in R 

`hashtagonly_tweets_INDEX = grep("^\\s*(?:#\\w+\\s*)+$", allTweets$V1,
                                value=F,
                                ignore.case = T,
                                fixed=F)`

Comment: Thanks - my error was to surround the grep pattern with / and / - for some reason I thought perl type syntax was expected.  `grepl("^\\s*(?:#\\w+\\s*)+$", "#hello #world") ` does return TRUE as expected.

Answer (score 1):

To determine if a specific tweet has only hashtags, you can use strsplit to tokenize it, and then search for entries in the list that don't start with "#". Consider tweet1 (only hashtags) and tweet2 (hashtags plus words).

```
tweet1 <- "#Traffic #in #Westminster #travel #roadrage #transport #London #tourism #sightseeing #dark #clouds"
tweet2 <- "#Traffic in #Westminster #travel #roadrage #transport #London #tourism #sightseeing #dark #clouds"

haswords <- function(tweet) {
    strings <- strsplit(tweet,' ')
    for (word in 1:length(strings[[1]])) {
        if (substring(strings[[1]][word],1,1) != '#') {
            return (TRUE)
        }
    }
    FALSE
}
```

The function `haswords()` returns TRUE for tweet2 and FALSE for tweet1.